Why datatables customization does not work at double letter columns?
I have a monthly timesheet datatable, which I export to Excel. But when I open the Excel, the row contains the days of the month (header row) is shown as number. I want to display as date.
Here is the displayed Excel
I added the following code snippet. It works but only until the Z column, and it doesn't work in AA, AB, AC, etc. columns.
customize: function(xlsx, row) {
       var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                            
        // Add date format to first line - not work for AA, AB,etc.
        $('row:eq(1) c', sheet).attr('s', '67')

        // Add number format for column A excel recognized as date
        // this work on every column
        $('row c[r*="A"]', sheet).attr('s', '0')

},

Is there any other way to do this?

Your jQuery selector $('row:eq(1) c', sheet).attr('s', '67') works correctly. It does handle AA, AB and so on, as you want. But then you use this:  $('row c[r*="A"]', sheet).attr('s', '0') - and this overwrites the styles of all the columns which begin with A (using r *= "A"). So, that is why AA, AB and so on are not formatted as expected. You will also see that the very first column A has the same issue, if you look at its style for that specific row, since A also begins with A.

If you want to create a row which uses an Excel date format (style 67) and also which uses bold font (fontId="2") then you need to create a new style - one which is not included in the set of pre-defined styles provided by DataTables. You can take a look at this answer to see how to create a new style - bearing in mind that your specifics are different from those in that answer.

Final note: the jQuery :eq() selector is deprecated. You can use what they recommend instead, or use this: $('row[r="2"] c', sheet)... in a solution which uses that new style I mention above.

@andrewJames Thanks, that's the solution! I modified to select only the A column instead of all begin with A, and it works perfectly.

Your approahc is correct. unfortunately excel handles a row different beyond Z column... after Z the format changes and the code fails.
So what u need to do is to grab the row and loop over each cell itself to fill the entire row:


customize: function(xlsx, row) {
    var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
    
    var firstRow = $('row:eq(1)', sheet);
    firstRow.children().each(function() {
        $(this).attr('s', '67');
    });



but careful! this will add ALOT of columns to the first row (10k+)
So you need to add a exit point:


    var firstRow = $('row:eq(1)', sheet);

    var maxCol = 36;
    var currentCol = 0;

    firstRow.children().each(function() {
        if (currentCol < maxCol) {
            $(this).attr('s', '67');
            currentCol++;
        } else {
            return false; // exit loop
        }
    });




thanks, but unfortunetely it doesn't work for me. I did a trick, but it's a half solution. In format header I replace '-' to '.', so the Excel keep the YYYY.MM.DD format, and doesn't convert to number. Although any other style (such as bold, etc) still doesn't work.
format: { header: function(text, index, node) {  return text.includes('-') ?   text.replaceAll('-', '.'):    text;     },},

"excel handles a row different beyond Z column" - no, I don't think it does - and anyway, that is not relevant to what the OP is describing - which is related to their jQuery selectors (operating on XML) - but is not related to how Excel then reads that data. There is also no need for any of the looping logic shown in the answer.
